# Using embedded JS (CORS+AJAX requests) to log in securely across domains

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

- Imagine I run `sso.com`, one central site for sign-on, with a CORS-enabled API
- I want to run 20+ *static* websites (e.g. generated by [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/)) on other domains, e.g. `static1.org`, `static2.net`.
- Is it **possible** and is it **safe** to render client-side "Logged in as X", "Go To My Dashboard" (etc) on those static sites?

  - I imagine they would need to perform an cross-domain AJAX request to `sso.com`.
  - This would check cookies and fetch authenticated user data.
  - It could then drop widgets into the static page. Mostly those widgets would link across to `sso.com`.

I am unable to find any examples of this scenario being done in practice. Is that because it's actually a security problem? Would we need to be very careful about the approved list of CORS domains?

Comment: You should read https://staticapps.org/articles/authentication-and-authorization/

Comment: @approxiblue: Thanks. Unrelated, but I think your decision to remove the Jekyll/Hugo tags means it is unlikely anybody who's built a similar infrastructure will now see this question.

Comment: I remove them because I think your question applies to static sites in general, but you could add them back if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like how data is served to big websites (Facebook, Google, etc).

As far as security goes, as long as you are **authenticating server-side**, and **making sure that crucial account actions** (saving things to the database, altering the database etc etc) are **done server-side**, then you should be perfectly safe in doing this.

**The key here is just making sure that sensitive data is handled by the server and not the client**. If you keep that in mind, you can build the application with security in mind. Also, **never trust user input**.

I hope this helps!

Comment: All good advice. Can you point to any FB/Google properties which are doing this? I can see YouTube and Gmail are sharing login state but I have no idea how they're achieving this...

Comment: You need help on the approach?

Comment: Well, I've just realised that the approach outlined in my question is not the same as the approach taken by Youtube+Gmail. Possibly not relevant to the above discussion of cookie security.

Comment: If you go stateless like this, you'd have to send the static site a token that it is able to use to authenticate users. This is what `Google` and `Facebook` do for websites that want to use their login.

Comment: Big service providers use [oauth2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) and it is pretty hard thing to implement properly.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak - we use this approach with some of our services at Vevo. It's not that hard

Comment: @OliverQueen So please take a look at this: http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/26/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/ - an author of Oauth2: _To be clear, OAuth 2.0 at the hand of a developer with deep understanding of web security will likely result is a secure implementation. However, at the hands of most developers – as has been the experience from the past two years – 2.0 is likely to produce insecure implementations._

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with oAuth. You definitely have no idea what you're talking about. @arturgrzesiak

Comment: Here is a proof that google uses actually ouath2: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer and still again similar expert: 

_Note: Given the security implications of getting the implementation correct, we strongly encourage you to use OAuth 2.0 libraries when interacting with Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoints. It is a best practice to use well-debugged code provided by others, and it will help you protect yourself and your users. For more information, see Client libraries._ 

if you still think it is not that hard to implement then I have no more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the input Artur but I OAuth for multiple dynamic servers. Not a static site architecture like the one I've outlined. Really this is about authentication not authorization: http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/04/01/openid-versus-oauth-from-the-users-perspective/

Comment: Be sure to checkout the OWAPS documentation. This is the link to CORS - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/About_OWASP